# texarea behavior is different in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have the following code:

test.html:

```
 <textarea class ="errortext" rows="1" cols="30" value=""> </textarea>
```

test.css:

```
textarea.errortext {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y:  hidden;
    overflow-x:  hidden;
    overflow:    -moz-scrollbars-horizontal;
    width:auto; height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }
```

In IE it works as expected I see a box to 1 row and 30 colomns and the box is non-resizable. In Firefox this is not true and the box is resisable.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, to prevent a textarea from being resizable in FF, add the following to your selector:

```
textarea.errortext {
    resize:none;
}
```

Comment: Note that this also applies to Chrome.

Comment: Thank you ozk, it works! Another question if you don't mind :) When I put my cursor in the textarea I can type anything and this might exceed 30 columns:
- How can I block the user from typing anything?
- How can I limit the text inside to 30 colums?

Thank you

Comment: you should probably open a new question for this. But the solution would be to listen on 'keypress' events on the textarea, and if the current content of the textarea > 30 just return false to disable the key from registering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `resize: none`.